# What can I say about the sum of values of the covariances of a Gaussian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}$ where $d$ is larger than $m$ such that each $A_{ij}$ is sampled from a Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $1$ (independently).

Now let $B = A A^{\top}$.

What can I say about the quantity $\sum_{i,j} B_{ij} - \sum_i B_{ii}$?

I would like to say (and believe) it is close to $0$ (because on expectation $E[B] = cI$), but I am not sure how to show that.

EDIT: I would like, if possible, an answer that it is close to 0, without strong dependence on the dimensions $d$ and $m$. I get the sense that many of the $B_{ij}$ should cancel with respect to being positive and negative, which is why I hope it won't be something like $d^2 \epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$, but something nicer with respect to $d$.

EDIT: I found here (Corollary 2.1) something that might be useful:

https://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/386/Concentration.pdf

My question is, I guess, would the function $g(A) = \sum_{ij} B_{ij} - \sum_{i} B_{ii}$ be considered Lipschitz-continuous in each variable separately, as the corollary requires?

Comment: There is no reason that the $B_{ij}$ approximately cancel. Don't forget that the variance matrix is symmetric : $B_{ij}=B_{ji}$.

Comment: @JeanMarie, but surely not all dot products are positive, and not all are negative (of the matrix $A$). Can't they cancel each other?

Comment: No, the different covariances may all be positive (think to variables like (weight, size, volume) for random size cubes made in the same wood)...

Comment: Is $g(A) = \sum_{ij, i \neq j} B_{ij} - \sum_{i} B_{ii}$ (I have added $i \neq j$) ?